# R Data Table: How to combine a list of data frame into single Data table

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following list of data frames. I want to combine them together and store the result in a data table

```
A <- data.frame(A=1:3)
B <- data.frame(B=4:6)
AB_List <- list(A,B)
```

One of the ways to achieve this is

```
AB_df <- data.table(do.call("cbind", AB_List))
```

Is there any other way to directly get the result, without wrapping it explicitly

Comment: `data.table(A, B)` or `as.data.table(AB_List)`.

Comment: You beat me to it, @djhurio. You should post it as an answer.

Comment: @djhurio : I have the list of 50 such dataframes. Should I run it in loop?

Comment: You can probably just do `do.call(data.table, AB_List)`. Though `as.data.table(AB_List)` should work for the whole list.

Comment: @DavidArenburg What's the benefit of using do.call instead of as.data.table?

Comment: @creativename Don't think there is any benefit. I was just addressing the comment above.

Comment: @creativename With `L = list(data.frame(a=1), data.frame(a=2))`, they are different: `do.call(data.table, L)` preserves duplicate names, while `as.data.table(L)` disambiguates them. Each one can be beneficial, depending on what you want to happen there.

Answer (score 3):

If you have data frames in a list, `as.data.table` will work. See example.

```
require(data.table)

AB_list <- lapply(seq(LETTERS), function(i) {
  df <- data.frame(A = (3*i-2):(3*i))
  names(df) <- LETTERS[i]
  df
})

as.data.table(AB_list)
```

To get a list of data frames you need to get a vector of data frame names using `ls()` and argument `pattern` or `grep()`. After that you can create a list of data frames.

```
df_names <- LETTERS
df_list <- mget(df_names)
```